# Online API for executing code

Tags: api, web-services

I am looking for a web api that can execute programs and return the result. The language would be specified, and it would be given stdin, and then would send back stdout (and maybe stderr.)

- Should support a large number of languages
- Accesses through an API

  - Code and language can be entered manually, but stdin must be able to specified via the API
- Sends back stdout
- Free would be good
- Bonus

  - If it leaves the program running to receive more stdin
  - Gives stderr as well

The purpose is that on http://codegolf.stackexchange.com, we often run "KoTH" challenges, but it is a challenge dealing with all the different languages. If there was an API to execute the code for us, it would be a lot easier.

Answer (score 2):

I tagged this question to see if something interesting came up, and sadly it doesn't seem like it does. However here are some online editors, and a thought regarding the Ideone API...

### Some online editors

I guess you've heard of these which are found searching for [online compiler editor](//google.com/search?q=online+compiler+editor), and possibly already use one or two of them:

- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/codingground.htm
- http://compileonline.com/
- https://ideone.com/
- https://www.codechef.com/ide

With slight variations these provide multiple languages, and different options for running your software online. But most of them only allows for stdin to be put into a textbox on the html page, and provides not only a pure stdout back.

And although not tested, I hardly doubt they are able to communicate with other programs, or to keep stdin open. That is not something easily done using the HTTP protocol.

### A closer look at Ideone

When further specifying the search into [online compiler editor with stdin api](//google.com/search?q=online+compiler+editor+with+stdin+api), most of these fell out, but Ideone remained and in the reference for *CodeTwist* it says: "CodeTwist uses Ideone API © by Sphere Research Labs". This indicates that there might be a little hope for you...

The description of Ideone says this about it self:

> ### Ideone is powered by: Sphere Engine™
>
> **Ideone is an online compiler which attracts hundreds of thousands of users every month.**
>
> *But do you know the technology which powers Ideone?*
>
> Your favourite compiler runs using Sphere Engine™, a proprietary technology bringing you far more possibilities than just code execution.
>
> - Sphere Engine™ executes your code on remote servers thanks to a simple API.
> - Sphere Engine™ supports 60+ programming languages, which are kept up-to-date and come equipped with both popular and non-standard libraries.
> - Sphere Engine™ works in a complete & secure runtime environment.
> - Sphere Engine™ comes with an optional module and Content Management System for setting programming challenges and programming contests.
> - Sphere Engine™ is used commercially in: recruitment, training & certification, education, programming contests & hackathons
>
> Just imagine how many things you could do with this powerful technology in the service of your company! You can try it out for free: visit [www.sphere-engine.com](//sphere-engine.com/?utm_campaign=permanent&utm_medium=sphereengine&utm_source=ideone) to see the demo version in action, consult the complete documentation, and the API.

To me this text *suggests* that it could be possible to use the API directly, and control what you send in, and how you respond to the return from the API. In other words, it *might* be possible to build your own solution where you send in code through the API with your stdin, and then redirect the stdout result back into another call triggering a different program.